# Sklearn mean_absolute_error gives always different values on the same data for different trials using data from spark df. How can I solve it?

Tags: python, pyspark, scikit-learn, databricks, loss-function

I want to calculate the mean average error (MAE) of to columns of a spark dataframe, but I cannot use `from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import RegressionMetrics` because I have high concurrency cluster.
Therefore, I use sklearn and convert to columns to pandas.

Here is my code:

```
mean_absolute_error(test.select("qty").toPandas(),test.select("pred").toPandas()) 
mean_absolute_percentage_error(test.select("qty").toPandas(),test.select("pred").toPandas())
```

Both MAE and MAPE gives different values every time I run it.
What can be the reason?
How can I solve it?

Btw: I am using databricks and I cannot share the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running `.toPandas()` the entire Spark dataframe is moved into the Driver node as a pandas DataFrame.
This is a very expansive operation that also makes use of the Drivers memory, so be careful.
In addition there is no guarantee what would be the **order** of the rows in the pandas df.

I think what happens is you run `.toPandas()` 4 times and each time you get the DataFrame in a different order.
this causes the changing results.

If you have to use pandas I recommend going `tmp = test.select('qty', 'pred').toPandas()` only once and then subsetting it to the MAE and MAPE functions.

Comment: You are right. That was the problem. Thanks!